# Wordpress how to use add_action inside plugin function

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I need to perform / call `woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees` action inside AJAX response function as below,

Requirement is to add a discount in a certain condition to the cart.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_tcf_et_add_estimate_to_cart', 'my_function' );
my_function()
{

    // ADD SOME PRODUCTS TO THE CART
    if( certain condition  )
    {
        add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'add_discount', 1, 1 );
        function add_discount( $cart )
        {
             global $woocommerce;
             $cart->add_fee( 'Discount' , -100 );
             return $cart;
         }
    }
    // some code    
}
```

I know this is completely wrong but seeking a way to do this in wordpress way? like write the `woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees` outside of `my_function` and call it if needed.

Is there any trick or technique to perform this or else is it not possible to do in Wordpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve this with use of the session. What I did was, add a key value to the session if my `certain condition` is true and then within the `woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees` check if the session has the and then add the Discount to the cart.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_tcf_et_add_estimate_to_cart', 'my_function' );
function my_function()
{
    if ( certain condition  )
    {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['_my_key_value'] = 'certain condition is true';
    }
}
```

and in side the `add_discount` function we check the session and add discount to the cart.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'add_discount', 1, 1 );
function add_discount( $cart )
{
    if ( isset( $_SESSION['_my_key_value'] )  )
    {
        $cart->add_fee( 'Discount' , -100 );

        // it is important to remove data from session once it is used
        unset( $_SESSION['_my_key_value'] ); 
    }
    return $cart;
}
```

Hope this help to someone.

Answer (score 2):

No, This is how you should do it.
You add your action hook to `woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees` like this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'add_discount', 1, 1 );
function add_discount( $cart )
{
    if ( certain condition  )
    {
        $cart->add_fee( 'Discount' , -100 );
    }
}
```

The `if` statement is then inside.

As for ajax request it would be the same but this time you don't have the `$cart` variable but instead use `WC()->cart`.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_tcf_et_add_estimate_to_cart', 'my_function' );
function my_function()
{
    if ( certain condition  )
    {
        WC()->cart->add_fee( 'Discount' , -100 );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this and is there anyway to call `add_discount( $cart )` from `my_function()`

Comment: Can you describe actually what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: `my_function` is a function that runs for a AJAX call in wordpress and according to my logic, I need to add a discount within the `my_function`. That is my requirement.

Comment: I see, can you please edit your original post and add the ajax code you're using... not all, just the add_action and the function name or something to make it a short but still meaningful.

Comment: Thanks for your update but is is not working for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171770/discussion-between-mapmalith-and-reigel).